# PyQt QtWebKit - Return value from a Python method directly to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt4, qtwebkit, method-signature

**EDIT:**

I've found a solution here:
[how do I correctly return values from pyqt to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372336/how-do-i-correctly-return-values-from-pyqt-to-javascript)

I'll post the code first:

Python code:

```
class JSBridge(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(JSBridge, self).__init__(parent)

    @pyqtSlot(bool)
    def fromJStoPython(self, param):
        print param
        print param.toBool()
    @pyqtSlot()
    def returnValue()
        return "hello world"

class another():
    ...
    view = QWebView()
    frame = view.page().mainFrame()

    param = "blabla"
    frame.evaluateJavaScript("printIt('" + param + "');")
    paramBool = True
    frame.evaluateJavaScript("fromPythonWithParameterBool('" + paramBool + "');")
```

JavaScript:

```javascript
function printIt(param)
{
    alert(param);
}
function toPython()
{
    jsBridgeInst.fromJStoPython(true);
}
// now here functions I've questions about:
function fromPythonWithParameterBool(param)
{
    alert(param);
}
function fromPythonReturnValue()
{
    res = jsBridgeInst.returnValue();
    alert(res);
}
```

**Now to my question:**

The `printIt` function works fine. So the param is interpreted as a String.
The `fromJStoPython` function also works fine. The print statement shows it's a `QVariant`.

But the `fromPythonWithParameterBool` function does not work, because I have to convert `paramBool` into a string in order to connect it. If I do so, it's printing the string value (but I want it to be boolean). Is it possible to pass a boolean, so that in JavaScript I can work with it as a boolean? If yes, how do you do it?

And for the `fromPythonReturnValue` function, it does not show an error, but `res` is undefined. Why?
I was searching for that problem, but mostly the examples/tutorials show standard stuff like:

```
evaluateJavaScript("alert('9')";)
```

I've worked with Java and SWT, and there I could just simply return a value (as in the `formPythonReturnValue` method). There was a Browser class where you could implement your methods to call, just like JSBridge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fromPythonWithParameterBool` doesn't work because you are not generating an input string that can be evaluated as javascript.

What you need to do is something like this:

```python
>>> script = 'fromPythonWithParameterBool(%s);' % str(bool(paramBool)).lower()
>>> print(script)
fromPythonWithParameterBool(true);
```

So the resulting string is now a fragment of valid javascript.

The problem with `fromPythonReturnValue` (as you already seem to have discovered), is that you are not specifying the type of the return value. This has to be done explicitly, using the [pyqtSlot decorator](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator):

```
    @pyqtSlot(result=str)
    def returnValue(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

Comment: Thx for the reply :D
I've tested it now also with a list as parameter and it works perfectly!

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I didn't delete the question. So it's practically possible to pass all type of arguments that evaluate to a JavaScript type. Which is nice

Comment: @ProgrammingIsAwsome. Sorry: I was replying to your first comment before you edited it (there seems to be a bit of a lag, sometimes).